# SQL COUNT items and GROUP over multiple categories with 0 totals for missing entries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery I would like to aggregate over a number of different categories (columns in the table) to produce a summary of the data, which is a simple COUNT and GROUP BY statement.  However, for this project I would like to produce a "complete" count of every permutation of the categories (the possible values of the categories are known ahead of time) with 0 totals for combinations without any entries for that permutation.

Here is the simple initial COUNT and GROUP statement:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(item.id) as total,
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(item.date, WEEK) as week,
  item.attribute_1,
  item.attribute_2,
FROM item
GROUP BY week, attribute_1, attribute_2
ORDER BY week DESC, attribute_1, attribute_2
```

where `attribute_1` has possible values `('A', 'B', 'C')` and `attribute_2` has possible values `('X', 'Y', 'Z')`
which produces something like this:

```
Row | total | week                    | attribute_1 | attribute_2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | A           | X
2   | 2     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | A           | Z
3   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | X
4   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | Y
5   | 3     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | Z
6   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | C           | Y
7   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | C           | Z
etc.
```

However my goal is to end up with a result like this:

```
Row | total | week                    | attribute_1 | attribute_2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | A           | X
2   | 0     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | A           | Y
3   | 2     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | A           | Z
4   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | X
5   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | Y
6   | 3     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | B           | Z
7   | 0     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | C           | X
8   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | C           | Y
9   | 1     | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 UTC | C           | Z
etc.
```

I found similar problems for a single category, so I can solve for that case by holding the other attributes constant with the following statement:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    item.id as item_id,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(item.date, WEEK) as week,
    item.attribute_1,
    item.attribute_2,
  FROM item
  GROUP BY week, attribute_1, attribute_2
  ORDER BY week DESC, attribute_1, attribute_2
),
category_1 as (
 select 'A' as name union all
 select 'B' union all
 select 'C'
)
SELECT
  category_1.name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(item_id) as total
    FROM data
    WHERE data.attribute_1 = category_1.name
    AND data.attribute_2 = 'X'
    AND data.week > TIMESTAMP('2020-07-10')
  ) as total
FROM category_1
```

which produces:

```
Row | name | total
------------------
1   | A    | 1
2   | B    | 1
3   | C    | 0
```

Is it possible to solve for the general case I am interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can generate the rows using a `cross join` and then match to the existing values:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(i.total), 0) as total,
       w.week, a1.attribute_1, a2.attribute_2
FROM (SELECT distinct TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, WEEK) as week FROM item) w CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT distinct attribute_1 FROM item) a1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT distinct attribute_2 FROM item) a2 LEFT JOIN   
     item i
     ON TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(i.date, WEEK) = w.week AND
        i.attribute_1 = a1.attribute_1 AND
        i.attribute_2 = a2.attribute_2
GROUP BY w.week, a1.attribute_1, a2.attribute_2
ORDER BY week DESC, attribute_1, attribute_2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7361076cc4b1d21f10d181fdf0fc43a9) is a db<>fiddle.  It uses Postgres, so there are some syntax tweaks for Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm still not getting 0 counts for the combinations without any items using your suggestion

Comment: @jeremyeastwood . . . Oops, the week was not coming from `w`; it was coming from `i`.  The change should fix your problem.

Comment: I believe `SUM(i.total)` -> `SUM(i.id)` in your code but otherwise this now works perfectly - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(item.id) as total,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(item.date, WEEK) AS week,
    item.attribute_1,
    item.attribute_2,
  FROM item
  GROUP BY week, attribute_1, attribute_2
), dict AS (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, WEEK)) AS weeks,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT attribute_1) AS attributes_1,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT attribute_2) AS attributes_2
  FROM item
)
SELECT IFNULL(total, 0) total, week, attribute_1, attribute_2
FROM dict, dict.weeks AS week, dict.attributes_1 AS attribute_1, dict.attributes_2 AS attribute_2
LEFT JOIN totals
USING(week, attribute_1, attribute_2)
-- ORDER BY week DESC, attribute_1, attribute_2
```

As you can see CTE `total` is your original query, next CTE `dict` is built dictionary of weeks, and attributes, the rest is just cross joins producing every permutation of weeks and attributes joined then on totals

Comment: yup, this also works as intended - appreciate the response